# Field Engineer Azure app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, azure, windows-8.1

I am trying to use the Azure Field Engineer app to develop on form my company. I can't get it to start from Visual Studio. I have tried to get all the Azure setting in the app, but I am missing something and I don't know where. I get the following error.

```
{
    Method: GET, 
    RequestUri: 'http://localhost:58972/tables/Job?$skip=0&$top=50&__includeDeleted=true&__systemproperties=__version%2C__deleted&$expand=equipments,customer,JobHistories', 
    Version: 1.1, 
    Content: <null>, 
    Headers: {
      X-ZUMO-FEATURES: QS,OL
      X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: b80fd36f-2574-4023-9630-a88edc3a6512
      Accept: application/json
      User-Agent: ZUMO/1.3 User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows Store; os_version=--; arch=X86; version=1.3.30130.0)
      X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/1.3 (lang=Managed; os=Windows Store; os_version=--; arch=X86; version=1.3.30130.0)
    }
}
```

> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.d__1d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<RequestAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.d__f.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<ReadAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.PullAction.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.TableAction.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncContext.d__3b.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceSyncContext.d__27.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>      at AzureMobile.Samples.FieldEngineer.DataModels.JobDataSource.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at AzureMobile.Samples.FieldEngineer.DataModels.JobDataSource.<GetAllJobs>d__30.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at AzureMobile.Samples.FieldEngineer.JobListPage.d__9.MoveNext()

I can't follow the direction on the following site as FieldEngineer  with Azure since it is already taken, so I set up my own app with services, as Field-Staff. Any suggestions/directions on how to get this app to run in Visual Studio?

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Field-Engineer-501df99d

Answer (score 0):

Project abandoned due to Microsoft ending Mobile Services.

Project restarted as Xamarin Android on Apps Services.

Microsoft's Notice at http://elink.clickdimensions.com/m/1/42635568/b12516-be848797-aa4e-4064-81ad-49f8383cc119/13/434/4d39c730-7d35-4093-abd8-f18109db0af2